# Is it possible to change url using vue-router without going to the page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

There is a shop on nuxtjs and on the /catalog page I need to make a "Load more" button. By clicking on it, products should be loaded and the url should be changed to /catalog/page_2  (?page=2 is not suitable).
If I change the url through $router.push nuxt goes to this page, but I need to change the url, but not go anywhere.
Is it possible to somehow undo the reloading but save the changes in the url?

history.pushState copes with the task, but in this case nuxt does not know that the url has changed and when clicking forward / backward in the browser nuxt does not load the goods needed for this page

Answer (score 1):

Paginations logically belong to the main page so It's good to consider them in URL queries, like `?page=2`.
also you can use `router.replace` to change queries.

```
this.$router.replace({
        query: { ...this.$route.query, page: this.page},
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But besides pagination, the customer wants the filters to be added to the url not through the get parameters. That is, the url should be like this
/categories/boys/shirts/color_red/size_s/material_cotton/page_2?order_type=asc&order_by=price

Answer (score 0):

Do it with this example
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-darkness-9ezn9?file=/pages/index/_id.vue
Now I can change the filters, categories, and the url changes, but the page does not reload

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to change the page if you are already on the correct one, check for differences in current page URL first;

```js
    const your_query = '?page=2' // containing url params
    const currPath = this.$route.fullPath; // containing current path + query params, e.g.  '/catalog/?page=2'
    const nextPath = `${this.$route.path}?${your_query)}`;

    if (currPath !== nextPath) {
      //"Abuse" router to change the current's windows url
      this.$router.replace(nextPath, undefined, () => {
      //If route navigation fails, e.g. due to a same-route navigation or wrong permissions in navigation-guards, handle here
        return;
      });
    }
```

Alternative would be to directly pass the new query params to the router, as:

```js
      this.$router.replace({ query:
         page: 2
      })
```